# How do I destroy a Unity Networking Match when app is shutting down?

Tags: unity-game-engine, application-shutdown, unity-networking

I've got a `ResetNetworkManager` method that's called when the server or client needs to clean up its state. One of these situations is when the server is shut down. This either happens when the `Stop Server` button is clicked, and when the method returns the `start` scene is loaded. In this situation the `MatchInfo` of the server's match is also passed in, and the `NetworkMatch.DestroyMatch` is called.

In the situation where the `Stop Server` button is clicked, everything works fine. The match is immediately removed from the match making service, and clients don't see it when they list matches.

However, when the server's app is shut down, the same method is called from another GameObject's `OnDestroy` method. However, in this situation the call doesn't seem to work, possibly because the `NetworkMatch.DestroyMatch` method actually starts a Coroutine, and this coroutine doesn't get far enough in its execution before it's killed with it's GameObject.

This is a problem as the server would normally run in `batchmode`, so the only way they get shut down is by killing them, rather than by clicking the button (only used when testing the server in `ui mode`.

Does anyone know how to make sure the match is destroyed when the app is suddenly shut down? I know you can't make `OnDestroy` a Coroutine, which would otherwise have been a nice solution...

Here is the code of the `ResetNetworkManager` method:

```
public void ResetNetworkManager(MatchInfo matchToDestroy)
{
    if (matchToDestroy != null)
    {
        matchMaker.DestroyMatch(matchToDestroy.networkId, 0, MatchDestroyed);
    }
    StopServer();
    StopClient();
    StopHost();
    StopMatchMaker();
    if (_gameStateManager != null)
    {
        NetworkServer.Destroy(_gameStateManager.gameObject);
        _gameStateManager = null;
    }
    Destroy(gameObject);
    NetworkServer.Reset();
}
```